# Jhipster: Navigation no longer works

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have successfully generated a monolithic jhipster 4.13 application and modified it to launch with a login page.

Here is the content of my app.route.ts:

```
export const APP_ROUTE: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomeLayoutComponent,
      data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
        pageTitle: 'home.title'
      },
      canActivate: [ UserRouteAccessService ],
      children: [
        { path: '', component: NavbarComponent, outlet: 'navbar' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: LoginLayoutComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        { path: 'reset', component: RegisterComponent },
      ]
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

The content of the app-routing.module.ts file:

```
const LAYOUT_ROUTES = APP_ROUTE;
[
    APP_ROUTE,
    navbarRoute,
    ...errorRoute
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(LAYOUT_ROUTES, { useHash: true })
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Here are the new layout template:
jhi-main:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

jhi-login-layout:

```
<jhi-page-ribbon></jhi-page-ribbon>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<jhi-footer></jhi-footer>
```

jhi-home-layout:

```
<jhi-page-ribbon></jhi-page-ribbon>
<div>    
    <router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card jh-card">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <jhi-footer></jhi-footer>
</div>
```

after those modifications, my app launch on login page as expected, after authentication i can reached my home page with the nav bar. il can also logout 
successfully, but i'm not longer able launch none of theses pages like:

```
"jhi-metrics", "jhi-health"; "jhi-configuration"; "audits" or "logs".
```

Any ideas?

After taking into account the suggestion of @sue to add { enableTracing: true }

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
NavigationStart(id: 7, url: '/home/(jhi-metrics)')
Router Event: RoutesRecognized

RoutesRecognized(id: 7, url: '/home/(jhi-metrics)', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home'), Route(url:'', path:'') }  } )
Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
GuardsCheckStart(id: 7, url: '/home/(jhi-metrics)', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home'), Route(url:'', path:'') }  } )
Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
GuardsCheckEnd(id: 7, url: '/home/(jhi-metrics)', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home'), Route(url:'', path:'') }  } , shouldActivate: true)
Router Event: ActivationEnd
ActivationEnd(path: 'home')
Router Event: ActivationEnd
ActivationEnd(path: '')
Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
Router Event: ActivationEnd
ActivationEnd(path: '')
Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
Router Event: NavigationEnd
NavigationEnd(id: 7, url: '/home/(jhi-metrics)', urlAfterRedirects: '/home')
```

Comment: Have you checked the authorithies on your routes?

Comment: Your trace does not show any ResolveStart/ResolveEnd so I guess the issue is with guards, this is why I asked you about authorities/roles. Which user are you logged in as? Could be also due to the routes you created or modified. Can you clarify what you modified?

Comment: I'm logged in with admin user and the only route i've added is APP_ROUTE.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I've noticed that when I call these views from the default path of the app  "/" it's ok, but a clic to another view from the first (example: "/jhi-metrics/(logs)" brings not Resolve and redirect (urlAfterRedirects) to "/jhi-metrics"

Answer (score 1):

https://angular.io/guide/router  Maybe help u.

Open the browser debug mode, and check the path that routing

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: I've added { enableTracing: true } to my AppRoutinModule and updated the post with the logs.

Comment: SUE that's a good suggestion, I have added it to JHipster in dev mode, it will be part of next release.